# How do I create a queue after reading my file?

Tags: java, split, queue, stack, text-files

```
FileReader r = new FileReader(stackfile);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(r);
String s, line = null;
int counter = 1;
while((s = reader.readLine()) !=null) {
    counter++;
    System.out.println(counter + "." + s);
}

queue.createQueue();
        
System.out.println("Queue is empty with" + queue.isEmpty());
queue.enqueue(s);
System.out.println("This is the queue");
queue.displayQueue();
    
System.out.println("\n\nDequeuing now");
String newString = (String)queue.dequeue();
    
System.out.println("New String is: " + newString);
String[] lineComponents = newString.split(",");
for(int i = 0; i < lineComponents.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Line components is [ " + i + "]: " + lineComponents );
    String[] binaryNumbers = lineComponents[i].split(";");
    for(int j = 0; j < binaryNumbers.length; j++) {
        System.out.println("Binary Numbers[" + j + "]:" + binaryNumbers[j]);
        for(int k = 0; k < binaryNumbers[j].length(); k++) {
            char c = binaryNumbers[j].charAt(k);
            System.out.print("Single Binary numbers [" + k + "]: " + c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's in the file?

Comment: [Read This](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/queue-interface-java/).

Comment: It depends on whether you are asking how to create a queue object, or put things into the queue, or write a queue class, or something else. Your question is unclear.  We can't answer your questions if we can't figure out what you are asking.